# With a mysql-connector-java as "provided" dependency, my Maven build cannot connect to the data store

Tags: maven, mysql-connector, maven-surefire-plugin

Because Tomcat tells us to have the mysql-connector-java in its lib/ directory, so that it can handle multiple projects, I had my dependency as provided:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.36</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And I extracted the jar archive mysql-connector-java-x.x.x-bin.jar from the downloaded dependency and copied it into the lib folder of the Tomcat server:

```
cp ~/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar lib/
```

But when I now run a build the tests phase fails since it cannot connect to the data store.

The build would succeed if commenting out the provided scope.

There must be a simple way around this...

UPDATE: I could run the Maven Tomcat 7 command: mvn clean install tomcat7:run -Denv="preprod" after adding the mysql-connector-java dependency in the tomcat7-maven-plugin plugin. But I still cannot run the tests, I have a connection failed when running the maven-surefire-plugin tests.

Answer (score 0):

I used both provided and test scopes as in:

```
<scope>provided test</scope>
```

and it now also make the connector in the tests phase.